# How do I set a schema on a BigQuery load job using a schema file stored in Google Cloud Storage using API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've created a python script to take a JSON file from a Google Cloud Storage bucket and load it into a dataset. 
I'm having issues trying to specify the schema which is in the same bucket as a text file

My schema file is a txt file with the format `Attribute:DataType,Attribute:DataType`

This is what I have

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()

schema_uri = 'gs://<bucket-name>/FlattenedProduct_schema.txt'
schema = schema_uri
job_config.schema = schema    
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
uri = 'gs://<bucket-name>/FlattenedProduct_JSON.txt'

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    dataset_ref.table('us_states'),
    location='US',  # Location must match that of the destination dataset.
    job_config=job_config)  # API request
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read the text file yourself and turn it into the format `schema` required, which is [List[google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField] – Schema of the destination table.](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.schema.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.schema)

Example of the required schema:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField

schem = [
     SchemaField('field1','STRING'),
     SchemaField('field2', 'INTEGER'),
     SchemaField('value', 'FLOAT')
    ]
```

Comment: how to build this from a .json file?

Comment: @rens look at this
https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.schema_from_json

Answer (score 0):

From your given code, you called txt file from your bucket however you used source format as JSON (SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON). You can review those lines to see if it works.

```
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
uri = 'gs://<bucket-name>/FlattenedProduct_JSON.txt'
```

Or as a workaround , you can also try below command to call a JSON format file either located in your local machine or from GCS. Following command specify a schema when you load your data.

`bq --location=[LOCATION] load --source_format=[FORMAT] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] [PATH_TO_DATA_FILE] [PATH_TO_SCHEMA_FILE]`

Where:

[LOCATION] is the name of your location. The --location flag is optional if your data is in the US or the EU multi-region location. For example, if you are using BigQuery in the Tokyo region, set the flag's value to asia-northeast1. You can set a default value for the location using the .bigqueryrc file.

[FORMAT] is NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON or CSV.

[PROJECT_ID] is your project ID.

[DATASET] is the dataset that contains the table into which you're loading data.

[TABLE] is the name of the table into which you're loading data.

[PATH_TO_DATA_FILE] is the location of the CSV or JSON data file on your local machine or in Google Cloud Storage.

[SCHEMA_FILE] is the path to the schema file on your local machine.

Alternatively you can also specify a schema in the API.

- To specify a schema when you load data, call the jobs.insert method and configure the configuration.load.schema property. Specify your region in the location property in the jobReference section.
- To specify a schema when you create a table, call the tables.insert method and configure the schema in the table resource using the schema property.

Please click [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specify-schema-manual-python) to see detail of those options.